# What type to store time length in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I was using :

```
total_time=datetime.time(int(total_time_text.replace("h","").replace("m","").split(" ")[0]),int(total_time_text.replace("h","").replace("m","").split(" ")[1]),0)
```

to store the time length.

But when I have :

```
total_time_text ="26h 50m"
```

I get an exception that

```
'hour must be in 0..23'
```

so the type "time" is not properly for this var. What I must to use?

Comment: You can take a look at `timedelta`: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html) for a lot of date/time examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a time length, you probably don't want to use `datetime.time` (which is inteded to be a specific time in a day rather than a duration). You should use [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) instead, or even a simple integer representing the number of seconds (or minutes).