# How to create a dictionary with time values as keys (m:ss) in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

what is the format for creating a dictionary that stores time values (minutes and seconds)? for example I want to create a dictionary the holds a runners sprint time: `mySprints = {"first":4:30,"second":3:13,"third":5:36}` and so on. In what format is the time entered in the dictionary?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580168/what-type-to-store-time-length-in-python) answer your question?

Comment: An array/list is probably a more appropriate data structure because the elements have an inherent order

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many methods, but one option would be to input the time as a string:

```
your_dict = {"first": "4:30","second": "3:13"}
```

Or you could use the time class within the datetime module:

```
example = datetime.time(0,4,30) # this would be 0 hours, 4 minutes and 30 seconds

your_dict = {"first": datetime.time(0,4,30),"second": datetime.time(0,3,13)} # etc...
```

You could also then create a lambda function to initiate the time a bit easier so you wouldn't have to write datetime.time(0, minutes, seconds) in the dictionary each time, for example:

```
time_obj = lambda m, s: datetime.time(0,m,s)

your_dict['third'] = time_obj(5, 36)

print(your_dict['third']) # this would return: 00:05:36
```

---

To answer your question in the comment, you can add timedelta objects together, for example:

```
x = datetime.timedelta(minutes=2, seconds=20) # notice the .timedelta this time
y = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1, seconds=10)

print(x+y) # returns: 0:03:30
```

To sort, you can sort a list of timedelta objects using python sorted() function, for example:

```
x = datetime.timedelta(minutes=2, seconds=20)
y = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1, seconds=10)
z = datetime.timedelta(minutes=0, seconds=50)

times = [x, y, z]

print(times)
# returns: [datetime.timedelta(0, 140), datetime.timedelta(0, 70), datetime.timedelta(0, 50)]

print(sorted(times))
# returns: [datetime.timedelta(0, 50), datetime.timedelta(0, 70), datetime.timedelta(0, 140)]
```

To sort it within a dictionary, I would suggest having a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value).

Comment: How are the string time values converted to time? I want to add up all the values to get a total time. and is it possible to sort the time values from lease to greatest?

Comment: In that case, don't use strings, rather use timedelta. I have added an answer to your questions above.